# select * where we have the reference value exists multiple times

Tags: python, sql, django

HI i need to fetch the data with the reference to some value, but the problem is the value exists multiple times

[image]

i need to fetch the all values with referencs to  userid

the function in my views is

```
> def rewardhistory(request):
>     cursor = connection.cursor()
>     reward = Rewardpoints_log.objects.get(userid='894490') 
>     return render_to_response('credits.html',{'reward':reward},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

but it throws the error multiple values exist

how can i do this please suggest

Comment: use `.filter()` method. `.get()` tries to get only ONE instance matches to condition.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`filter()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) instead of `get()`. `get` fetches only one result.

```
def rewardhistory(request):
    reward = Rewardpoints_log.objects.filter(userid='894490') 
    return render_to_response('credits.html', 'reward':reward},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I'm guessing you're not using any relationship between your models. I suggest you start doing that.

Answer (score 0):

BY USING FILTER IT GIVES

Rewardpoints_log: 202 >,

IN THE HTML FILE BY USING THIS

{{ reward }}

WHEN I TRY

{{ reward.rewardpoints }}

IT RETURNS NOTHING